# Web.config webServer rewrite rules for local and remote

Tags: iis, azure, ssl, web-config

I have an application that I want to run locally via http and remotely (on Azure) via https so I added this to my web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to https">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}"
                 pattern="Off"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}"
                 pattern="^get$|^head$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect"
                  url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

After deploying this to Azure it worked perfectly on the remote server but when I run it locally the re-route occurs and I get SSL connection errors because I don't have or want a local ssl cert.

I have tried using the rule below (with an extra input testing localhost) to overcome the local issue but it appears as if the damage is done and nothing else I have tried will get my local site to work again.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to https">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <!-- This has been added -->
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"
                 pattern="localhost"
                 negate="true"/>

            <add input="{HTTPS}"
                 pattern="Off"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}"
                 pattern="^get$|^head$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect"
                  url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Would anyone mind putting me out of my misery and explaining where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I've got it working now!

I'm sure some of my previous attempts should have worked as well but didn't realise I need to clear the cache within Chrome - I guess Chrome caches such redirects?

Anyway, I added this rule and deleted the cache and all is working as I'd expect!

```
<rule name="Redirect to http"
          stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"
                  trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"
             pattern="localhost" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

Hope some of this might help others in the future...